# Signal Processing Steps for Raw Accelerometer Data

Tags: normalization, signal-processing, filter

A project I am engaged with involves taking raw accelerometer data (in g's ) and analyzing for the existence of tremors (the accelerometer is attached to an individuals hand). I am relatively new to digital processing, and was interested in the steps necessary to remove any noise and eventually convert acceleration to velocity and displacement measurements.

I imagine this would entail some kind of filter for the de-noising, but am pretty in the dark for the rest. Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful with the dimensions of the data, like how many time series you have and the resolution. A simple plot of a piece of data is always nice too. Also check out [digital signal processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) they specialize on this type of questions! Good luck!

Comment: Some advice on processing accelerometer data is provided here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40354/how-should-i-normalize-my-accelerometer-sensor-data/40404#40404